# DATABASE AUTOMATED BACKUP ISSUE

Tags: sql-server

I am able to take full backup through this query but unable to take differential and transactionl back please help me out

```
USE lcmc

DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(200)

SELECT @MyFileName='d:\1-backup'  + REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(20),GetDate(),120),':','-') + 'full.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE [LCMC]  TO DISK=@MyFileName
```

Comment: What is the trouble you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow documentation at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191180%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

```
USE lcmc
DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(200)
SELECT @MyFileName='d:\1-backup' + REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(20),GetDate(),120),':','-') + 'full.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE [LCMC] TO DISK=@MyFileName 
WITH DIFFERENTIAL
```

Should do it